# Sending embedded survey email using MonkeySurvey API

Tags: java, rest, surveymonkey

What should be the body-text or body-html when doing a POST request using this API to create messages?

API - https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages

When I am inserting survey link in the body, I am not getting a clickable embedded question in the mail body like we get when using email collector from console.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building that format is not currently supported in the API, you can only create with a custom HTML.

That said you can *copy* a previous message that is in the right format through the API. From the link you specified: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages

It shows you can set a from collector/message to copy:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "from_collector_id": "<any_collector_id>",
    "from_message_id": "<message_id_from_provided_collector_id>"
}
```

That will take a copy of a message you already have created as a template and create a new message. Hopefully that could be a good workaround for your use case.